# CSS-Selector single rule

Tags: html, css, standards, w3c

Does anybody know whether the semicolon is required in a CSS -selector if there is only one command? I couldn't find in the w3c standrd.

```
body{color:red}
```

Or

```
body{color:red;}
```

Comment: It is optional for the last rule. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not required when you only have one style defined but if you have multiple ones defined it is required on all but the last one.

Comment: **1.** With such high rep, you should know that this should be a comment. **2.** There's already a dupe for this kind of mundane questions. Kindly close it as dupe, instead of answering.

Comment: This is pretty obviously an answer, I don't see why it should be a comment.

Comment: @BoltClock I gave my reasons. If both reasons are not enough, then I accept what you say. `:)`